# How can I count the UID under the UserID in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

It only counts the red mark, what I needed is the black mark.

[Link for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF5oo.png)

How do I retrieve the data?

```
String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();

public static final String TAG = "TAG";


DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("babylist").child(userID);

db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int counter = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        String userCounter = String.valueOf(counter);
        babycount.setText(userCounter);
        usercount.setText(userCounter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it only counts the red mark, what I needed is the black mark

That's the expected behavior since you are looping through the data only once. Calling `.child(userID)` will always count the number of children under the user ID node. To count all the children of all users, you need to add a nested loop like in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference babylistRef = db.child("babylist");
babylistRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            int userCounter = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    userCounter++;
                }
            }
            babycount.setText(userCounter);
            usercount.setText(userCounter);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```